# Get location of selected cell in Google Sheets and output to another cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets where I'm trying to output the coordinates of the selected cell to another cell.  Imagine a 10x10 grid beginning in Cell A1.  If I select A1 then the coordinates (1, 1) are outputted to a cell (let's say L1).  If I then selected B4, the coordinates (4, 2) would be in L1.  It's important for this to update every time a new cell is selected.  How might I do this?

Comment: You will probably need to use Google Apps Script to do something like that. But can I ask you a question... what is your larger goal? What are you trying to accomplish that makes what you describe necessary?

Also, you should consider making a public version of your spreadsheet and sharing it.

Comment: I'm making a dashboard for my fantasy football league.  Under "Individual Season Results" I'd like to be able to click on any individual game and have another cell pop up with information for that game.  I can do that part if I have the coordinates of which cell is selected.  Here's a view of what it looks like (please excuse the team names):  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nxy6ZjNwJrPRGTR3bD7QbxaqNyWiB3M4pBGNooPIF4U/pubhtml?gid=1785688778&single=true

Comment: Read my answer below. Feel free to "accept" or "upvote" it if it helps you. And also feel free to ask for more clarification in further questions or comments.

Answer (score 0):

Given your goal, I recommend you simply make each cell in your win-loss table a `hyperlink` to a separate file that contains the details of the game.

Something like:

```
=hyperlink("http://example.com","W")
```

Replace `http://example.com` with the path to the specific Google Doc you create for the details of each game summary.

If you don't have enough detail to warrant it's own individual file / GoogleDoc, then you could just insert a `note` (not a `comment`) if you have just a little bit of data about each game. Or if you have a little more details a middle ground solution would be to add a table where the columns are the data fields for each game and the rows are the individual games.

Otherwise, I think you will have to get into scripting to accomplish what you describe. And given your situation, I would not recommend that approach because, in my opinion, you have better options available that are simpler to accomplish your objective.